# import java class from GitHub

Tags: java, android, class, github

I need to import this library into my project but I don't know how to do it because there isn't a link or something like that.
How can I do it.
Here is the library: https://github.com/nomanr/ZoomTextView

In other libraries I used this code:

implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.3.0'

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the ZoomTextView.java file in your project from the link:-

https://github.com/nomanr/ZoomTextView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/noman/zoomtextview/ZoomTextView.java

and use that in creating your view. So, there is no need of implementing anything in your gradle.